# Prevent reload page when click on button take you to the same page link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, reload

I would like to prevent an HTML button that acts like a link take you to the same page from reload the page

For Example: prevent reload the website when click on logo if you are in Homepage.

How can I do this?

Full code: https://codepen.io/Muh-Ail/pen/oNpLKXM?editors=0010

```
   let activeBtn = document.querySelector(".active-btn");
   let currentLocation = location.href;

    if (activeBtn.href === currentLocation) {

        activeBtn.preventDefault();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
let activeBtn = document.querySelector(".active-btn");
let currentLocation = location.href;


if (activeBtn.href === currentLocation) {
    activeBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the `e.preventDefault();` from the listener `ele.addEventListener("click", function (e)` instead;

Also, you should wrap the js with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
// code here
});
```

You should add different links for you to be able to see.